# Unity3d направление движения относительно положения камеры

Tags: c#, unity3d

Встретил проблему, что не получается сделать движение в зависимости от положения камеры. Чтобы персонаж если и бежит вперед, то бежал строго от камеры. Моя реализация, которая вычисляет тангенс направления не работает...

```
internal sealed class Example
{
    private void Update()
    {
        if (_isDeath)
            return;

        if (_playerAnimation.GetRunningAnimation() == AnimationType.PlayAnimationAttack)
            return;

        _direction = new Vector3(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"), 0.0f, Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical")).normalized;

        if (_direction.magnitude >= 0.1f)
        {
            float angle = Mathf.Atan2(_direction.x, _direction.z) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0.0f, angle, 0.0f));
            _playerAnimation.PlayAnimation(AnimationType.PlayAnimationRun);

            _characterController.Move(_direction * _movementSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
        else
            _playerAnimation.PlayAnimation(AnimationType.PlayAnimationIdle);
    }
}
```